# Where is Docker container real location in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, docker

I recently installed Docker in Windows 10 (updated to Dec 2020). I can't find the real path of the container config. I need to change a container configuration.

It is not `C:\ProgramData\Docker\\` nor `C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\\`.
I searched everywhere and I cannot find the config files.

Can you help me find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration file might not exist but you can create it **C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json** and add all the configurations that you need.

```
{
    "authorization-plugins": [],
    "dns": [],
    "dns-opts": [],
    "dns-search": [],
    "exec-opts": [],
    "storage-driver": "",
    "storage-opts": [],
    "labels": [],
    "log-driver": "",
    "mtu": 0,
    "pidfile": "",
    "data-root": "",
    "cluster-store": "",
    "cluster-advertise": "",
    "debug": true,
    "hosts": [],
    "log-level": "",
    "tlsverify": true,
    "tlscacert": "",
    "tlscert": "",
    "tlskey": "",
    "group": "",
    "default-ulimits": {},
    "bridge": "",
    "fixed-cidr": "",
    "raw-logs": false,
    "registry-mirrors": [],
    "insecure-registries": [],
    "disable-legacy-registry": false
}
```

Worst case you can enter them from the Dashboard under the tab Docker Engine:

[image]

**Resources:**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon

Answer (score 0):

As per two-years old post, something has changed.
Just in case someone is using Docker Engine v.20.10 like myself, it stores config files (`config.json`, `daemon.json` and `features.json`) under the path:

```
c:\Users\<user_name>\.docker\
```